# help with this derivative involving transformation matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

I am working on an image analysis problem where I have a cost function which has the following term:

$$
U = f(M(p))
$$

Here $f$ is an image which is sampled at discrete locations $p$. $M$ is a rigid transformation matrix and it can be written as product of two rotations and two scaling matrices. $p$ are the spatial locations that we have sampled the image $f$ on. So, the spatial transformation through $m$, maps the points $p$ into new spatial locations to yield the transformed image $U$. The transformed image $U$ is generated by interpolating the intensities of the image $f$ at these new locations through a differentiable interpolating function like cubic splines.

Now, the problem is attempting to find the optimal rotation and scaling parameters (total 4 parameters to estimate) using conjugate gradient descent method, so I need to compute the gradient of my cost function which means differentiating this term. Now, the matrix $M$ can be written down as the product:

$$
M = (R_y) * (R_x) * (S_y) * (S_x)
$$

where the $R_*$ matrices are the rotation matrices in the x and y plane and $S_*$ matrices are the scaling matrices. So, I need to compute the derivative of $U$ with respect to the parameters I need to estimate. Now, let us consider the scaling matrix $S_x$. This can be written as:

$$
S_x = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
s_x & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} } \right]
$$

The derivative of this matrix wrt to the scaling parameter $s_x$ is simply the 2 by 2 identity matrix.

So, now to compute the derivative of the function $U$, I can apply the chain rule as:

$$
U' = f'(M(p)).M'(p)
$$

Considering the $M'(p)$ term, I was wondering if I can do as follows:

$$
M(p) = (R_y) * (R_x) * (S_y) * (S_x)(p)
$$

Taking the derivative wrt to $s_x$, I can consider $(R_y) * (R_x) * (S_y)$ as constants. So, I will have:

$$
M'(p) = (R_y) * (R_x) * (S_y) * (p)
$$

using the fact that the derivative of $S_x$ is the identity matrix. Does this seem correct?

The reason I ask this is because I was looking at some online implementation of such a software and in their implementation of this derivative, they do not have the $(R_y) * (R_x) * (S_y)$ term.

Comment: Your claim that "The derivative of this matrix wrt to the scaling parameter sx is simply the 2 by 2 identity matrix." is wrong; it's a $2 \times 2$ matrix with a $1$ in the upper left corner and zeroes elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I still do not see how those other constant terms will drop out.

Comment: I don't see either...I stopped reading at about the point where you made this mistaken assumption. But now that I've read it, what you'll get is $R_y R_x S_y S_x'$. The rightmost product will be just $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&s_y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$; the next product will have the first col of $R_x$ as its first col, and the second col will be zero; the last product will .. wait a minute. What exactly are $R_x$ and $R_y$? A rotation in the $xy$-plane has only a single parameter (angle)...so I don't know what your equations mean.

Comment: Damn, I made another mistake. I was doing things in 3D and then wanted to show the problem in 2D and made a stupid mistake. There will, of course, be a single rotation matrix.

Comment: OK. Then the product will end up being a matrix whose first column is the first column of $R$, and whose second column is zero. Is this, perhaps, what the code you've looked at actually has in it?

Comment: Nah, the code does not have any contribution from the rotation matrices, unfortunately. Perhaps, that code is wrong. Thanks for your help. I will look further and will update the thread if I discover something new.

Comment: Observe that if you're going to compute the norm of $U$, then the rotation may not matter, since it's norm-preserving...perhaps that's part of what's going on.

Comment: Could you elaborate in the last comment? Perhaps, I should create a new thread with the corrections you mentioned and the full problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16874/discussion-between-john-and-luca).